# audio_waveforms can't find audio file

Tags: flutter, audio-player

I am using `audio_waveforms` to handle audio messages inside my chat app. I am facing a problem where when I try to call `await player.preparePlayer(path: path);` to prepare my player where the path is given with the message. I am currently testing with local .wav audio files located in my assets/audio. I added the folder in my `pubspec.yaml`. I am creating `late PlayerController player;` in GroupMessage class and then call
`Future initializePlayer(String path) async { player = PlayerController(); await player.preparePlayer(path: path); }`

using a FutureBuilder so that I can wait for the controller to be initialized correctly. But it throws the following error:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 6022): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 6022):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 6022):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:644)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 6022):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:616)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 6022):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 6022):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 6022):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 6022):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/audio/arabian-psy-vox_138bpm_F.wav: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I don't know why it can't see the file, can someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution & it needs a package named [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider).

So, your `pubspec.yaml` file should look like this:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/sound.wav
```

Here's the `main.dart` file. So, here's a different way in this plugin if your sound file is not in the native folder.

```
import "dart:io";

import "package:audio_waveforms/audio_waveforms.dart";
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:flutter/services.dart";
import "package:path_provider/path_provider.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final PlayerController controller = PlayerController();
  String path = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (Duration timeStamp) async {
        final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        const String assetName = "sound.wav";
        final File file = File("${directory.path}/$assetName");
        final ByteData byteData = await rootBundle.load("assets/$assetName");
        await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List());
        path = file.path;
        setState(() {});
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              AudioFileWaveforms(
                size: const Size(double.infinity, 100),
                playerController: controller,
                playerWaveStyle: const PlayerWaveStyle(
                  liveWaveColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (controller.playerState.isPlaying) {
                    await controller.stopPlayer();
                  } else {}
                  await controller.preparePlayer(path: path);
                  await controller.startPlayer();
                },
                child: const Text("Play"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```